# How to run vuejs files on IIS

Tags: vue.js, iis, vuejs2, requirejs, iis-8

So am using a vueJS Example as a demo for learning purposes which uses a **requirejs-vue** as a component loader.
when i run the server on Live-Server extension of VS-code (a simple http server), it run correctly with no problems.
However, when i run this example on IIS server (version 8.5) on windows 8.1, it through ***404 Error*** *app.vue* does not exist.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

and in the Network devtool, i can see that every module is loaded correctly, except for *.vue files,

VueJS Example :
https://plnkr.co/edit/Y2cEa3?preview

Web Config for IIS that am using:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

PS: i have also run an other example that uses ***http-vue-loader*** instead of **requirejs-vue** and IIS still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to set mimeType for the “.vue” extension file to use `httpvueloader`/`requiresjs_vue`.
[image]
In addition, we could manually add it to a `Web.Config` file, which can be recognized by IIS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".vue" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.